# ocl constraint with recursive class

Tags: recursion, constraints, ocl

For a little bit of context: a `Class` can have other `Class` as `Requirement` to be taken by a student. The `Class` is taken by a `Student` via a `ClassGroup` which can be ordered in time with its attribute `sessionYear`.

[image]

I want to put an OCL invariable constraint that will check if, for the `sessionYear` a `ClassGroup`, its `Class` `Requierement` were already taken before this `sessionYear`.

in other words: `sessionYear` for `Requirement` < `sessionYear` for `Class`

I tried a quite a few constaints and my closest attempt was this one:

`context Etudiant inv C6: if ClassTaken->notEmpty then 
 classTaken->forAll(ct|ct.class.Requirement.OfferedGroup->collect(sessionYear)->forAll(sy| sy < cs.sessionYear))
 else true endif`

But the problem is, in the `forAll(sy| sy->sy < cs.sessionYear)`, `sy` won't be the `Student` required `ClassTaken` for a `ClassGroup`, but rather a Bag with every instances of `OfferedGroup` that are `Requirement` for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this something like this:

```
context Student
 inv C6: inscription->forAll(insc|ClassTaken.class.Requirement->forAll(prer|inscription->exists(preIns|preIns.ClassTaken.class = prer 
 and if preIns.ClassTaken = insc.ClassTaken then true
  else preIns.ClassTaken.sessionYear < insc.ClassTaken.sessionYear endif)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying quite a few constraints is hacking and does not always lead to a satisfactory result in a reasonable period of time.

OCL is a moderately readable formal language.

Once you express the intent of your constraint clearly in English (or French or ...) you should find that it can be transliterated relatively easily into OCL.

Think/design do not hack.